# Java Bank Interest/Savings Calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I am very new to Java and am trying to create a Bank Savings and Interest calculator. I have created the basic calculator but upon adding some new features to this calculator, I seemed to have screwed it up and it no longer performs any of the tasks it previously would.

A few things I am trying to accomplish with this calculator:
1. Choose your type of account (Savings, CD, or Checking) and pass to my Account object that extends the JFrame.

1. Prompt user for the original balance, interest rate and period length. Pass these values to the Account object (this is the part I can't figure out).
2. Print the final balance after Calculate button is clicked.
3. Ask user "Want to open new account? Yes/No" If yes, loop back. If no, exit.

I am lacking in some basic Java knowledge which is why I am stuck now. ANY help is appreciated!

Account.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Account extends JFrame {

private int period;
private int balance;
private int rate;
private String printstring;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Period: " + period + ", Balance: " + balance);
}

public int getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(int period) {
    this.period = period;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getPrintstring() {
    return printstring;
}

public void setPrintString(String printstring) {
    this.printstring = printstring;
}

public void calculate() {
    for ( int i = 0; i<period; i++)
{
    balance = (balance * rate) + balance;

}
}
}
```

Banker.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Banker {

// Array for type of bank account

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    // Declare strings for period, balance, rate
    String period;
    String balance;
    String rate;

    // Prompt user for input
    period = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of periods (length):");
    balance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Beginning balance:");
    rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Interest rate (use decimal, example: .05     = 5%):");

    // Make Calculate button
    JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    // Make 3 Labels
    JLabel blabel = new JLabel("Period: " + period);
    JLabel plabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);
    JLabel flabel = new JLabel("Final Balance: " + balance);

    // Setup window with flow layout and exit on close
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Interest Savings Calculator Plus");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Add combo box, calc button and labels
    frame.add(calculate);
    frame.add(plabel);
    frame.add(blabel);
    frame.add(flabel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] accttype = { "Checking", "Savings", "CD" }; // Array of bank acct types
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose account...",
    "Choose bank account type", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
    accttype, // Array of acct types
    accttype[0]); // First choice
System.out.println(input);


    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            createAndShowGUI();
        }



}
```

Comment: Where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: So this is the first thing that you should learn from this: Use some sort of version control like git or mercurial, so that you alwyas can go back to a previous working version. Also have a look into junit or testng. It all ma seem like a lot of new things, but in the end the benefit is great.

Answer (score 1):

I only have a general advice for you...

You are working with Money, well please don't use `float` and/or `double` as a datatype.

In `float` and `double` types it is impossible to represent 0.1 (or any other negative power of ten) as a `float` or `double` exactly.

For example, suppose you have €1.03 and you spend 0.42 How much money do you have left?

System.out.println(1.03 - .42);
prints out 0.6100000000000001.

The right way to solve this problem is to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) as a datatype, and it has all the methods like add, divide, ... and so on.
One pitfall, `BigDecimal` is immutable don't forget about that when you do your calculations.

Comment: As a sidenote to this, it's funny to see everybody always tells you never to do calculations wth money using doubles. But in ten years working in the insurance sector, I have not even once come across a program that is _not_ using doubles. I wouldn't advise anyone to use doubles though, but in some cases using doubles actually works if you do it right, and sometimes using something like BigDecimal isn't an option for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you prompt for Account type you'll want to prompt and capture the input for the values you need:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Question:");
```

This gives you a String which you need converted to a number:

```
double value;
try {
  value = Double.parseDouble(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  //Handle the exception
}
```

You can do this for all the inputs you need. After that pass them to your Account object.

```
Account account = new Account();
account.setBalance(value);
```

I'm hoping you can extrapolate your needs from there! Good luck.